# Turn off https in Wordpress 4

Tags: https

I have a site that uses [wpmegamenu](http://wpmegamenu.com/) to direct people to several non-wordpress pages in an iframe.

I just upgraded to 4.0.1 and it moved everything to https. (which is great!) But this means that the pages that get shown in an iframe are blocked as a `mixed content` error.

Is there a way to turn off https and have all the fun of 4.0.1 without the https? (So that we can upgrade the pages that lag behind in security without holding up the man thrust of the action.)

I've tried changing `wp-config.php` and adding `define('FORCE_SSL', false);` but it made no difference.

There is an option in the settings page `wordpress-https_secure_external_urls` but it is [serializd](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24694/correct-way-to-serialize-the-data-of-options-table). It seems to be a place to whitelist http pages, but I have no idea how to get urls onto that list.

Comment: I don't know of anything in WordPress 4 that would force or unforce ssl, I suspect the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: WordPress has NOT moved your web to SSL and the option `wordpress-https_secure_external_urls` is not anywhere in WordPress; if that option is in your WordPress is because you have installed a third party plugin or you have code it at your own.